# how to show/hide maximize/minimize button in custom titlebar in electron

Tags: html, electron, angular9

So far I made a custom titlebar in electron (using angular 9) added those buttons to the html and click events respectively to minimize, maximize, restore or close the window. Now problem arises when user either double click the title bar( since css property is set as `-webkit-app-region: drag`) or user uses window snap feature to maximize the window. For, double click I thought of using dblclick event in angular but still failed. So, how can I address this problem ?

titlebar.component.html

```html
<div class="titlebar" *ngIf="showTitleBar" (dblclick)="dblFunction()">
   
   <div class="navigation">
      <a class="normal-button material-icons" *ngIf="showBackButton">arrow_back</a>
      <div class="appTitle">{{title}}</div>
   </div>
   
   <div class="wincontrol">
      <a class="normal-button material-icons" (click)="minimize()">remove</a>
      <a class="normal-button material-icons" *ngIf="showMaxButton ; else showResButton" (click)="maximize()">crop_square</a>
      <ng-template #showResButton>
         <a class="normal-button material-icons" id="restore" (click)="restore()">flip_to_front</a>
      </ng-template>
      <a class="close-button material-icons" (click)="close()">clear</a>
   </div>
   
</div>
```

titlebar.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WindowService } from 'src/app/services/window.service';
import { ElectronhelperService } from 'src/app/services/electronhelper.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-titlebar',
  templateUrl: './titlebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./titlebar.component.scss']
})
export class TitlebarComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Electron-App' ;
  showMaxButton ;
  showTitleBar = true ;
  showBackButton = false ;

  constructor(private win: WindowService, private helper: ElectronhelperService){
    this.showMaxButton = !this.win.winSettings.wasMaximized ;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  minimize(){
    this.win.sendMinimize() ;
  }

  maximize(){
    this.showMaxButton = !this.showMaxButton ;
    this.win.sendMaximize() ;
  }

  restore(){
    this.showMaxButton = !this.showMaxButton ;
    this.win.sendRestore() ;
  }

  close(){
    this.win.sendClose() ;
  }

  dblFunction(){
    console.log('dbl clicked')
    this.showMaxButton = !this.showMaxButton ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally after looking all over internet, problem caused due to zone as it was running outside of angular's code.

titlebar.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { WindowService } from 'src/app/services/window.service';
import { ElectronhelperService } from 'src/app/services/electronhelper.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-titlebar',
  templateUrl: './titlebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./titlebar.component.scss']
})
export class TitlebarComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Electron-App' ;
  showMaxButton ;
  showTitleBar = true ;
  showBackButton = false ;
  constructor(private win: WindowService, private helper: ElectronhelperService, private zone: NgZone){
    this.showMaxButton = !this.win.winSettings.wasMaximized ;

    this.helper.win.on('maximize', this.toggleMaxButton.bind(this)) ;
    this.helper.win.on('unmaximize', this.toggleMaxButton.bind(this)) ;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  minimize(){
    this.helper.win.minimize() ;
  }

  maximize(){
    this.helper.win.maximize() ;
  }

  restore(){
    this.helper.win.unmaximize() ;
  }

  close(){
    this.helper.win.close() ;
  }

  toggleMaxButton(){
    this.zone.runTask(() => {
      if (this.helper.win.isMaximized()){
        this.showMaxButton = false ;
      }
      else{
        this.showMaxButton = true ;
      }
      console.log(this.showMaxButton)
    }) ;
  }
}
```

Since, `win.on` events are asynchronous ngZone was required to toggle the boolean value inside angular. It took literally a week to solve this issue !